# rest api(POST Method) in ionic 2 not working on android device

Tags: android, rest, ionic2

We are building an application in ionic 2 using API, api calls working fine on browser(used proxy Server) .

After android build(removed proxy server) GET method is working fine on device but POST method is not working. It is an API for user authentication so getting 403 forbidden error.

Below is the code:-
**Home.ts**

```
this.authService.checkAuthentication().then((res) =>{
  console.log("Already authorized");
 this.data = res;
}, (err) => {
  this.data = 'error occured';
});
```

Auth.ts(Auth Provider)

```
 checkAuthentication() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let credentials = {
        email: 'test@test.com',
        password: 'password'
      };
      let headers = new Headers();
      headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        headers.append('X-XSRF-Token', 'kK4GDdiHAHejPeoXl4dL1AAgb13eiEwPhxvDw=');
      let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
      this.http.post(API_URL, JSON.stringify(credentials), options)
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe((data) => {
          resolve(data);
        }, err => {
          reject(err);
        });
    });
  }
```